# How to simply get Facebook public page post feed

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api, permissions, feed

It seems to me I am delving unnecessarily deep into GraphAPI and app creation to do this simple thing, but I can't figure out any other way.

What I want for my personal website(nothing connected to Facebook) is to insert a feed from a public Facebook page, much like the [FB page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/), but I need only about three latest posts and need to style them completely differently.
I tried to do it through [FB Page Feed guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v14.0/page/feed#page-feed) with GraphAPI and also PHP SDK, but both say:

> This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_user_content' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature.

...and to get Page Public Content Access, I need successful review of my app.
That doesn't seem to make much sense to me. I don't want to develop an app, I already have created a website and just want to insert public page feed in there. What am I missing?

Comment: Using the plugin, or going the API route and requesting access to the feature, are you only two options.

Comment: Facebook has restricted what "public" information can be requested via API, a lot, over the years - especially after that Cambridge Analytica thing broke. If anyone had free API access to every piece of public information - then it would be easy to "suck" that data out of Facebook en masse. Scraping all that same data from their frontend result pages, would require more effort, and is easier for them to detect and block.